# Waiting for promise to resolve from parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis

I have a primary thread in my node application such as this:

```
function main_thread() {
  console.log("Starting");
  values = get_values(1);
  console.log(values);
  console.log("I expect to be after the values");
}
```

The `get_values` function calls the `hgetall` function using the [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) package. This function provides a call back, but can be promisified:

```
function get_values(customer_id) {
  // Uses a callback for result
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    redis_client.hgetall(customer_id, function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log("About to resolve");
      resolve(result);
    });
  })
  .then(({result}) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

This works great for promise chaining within the function, however not so well in my main thread, as I can't wait and return the value.

Here's how I'd do it in ruby, the main language I use:

```
def get_values(customer_id)
  return @redis_client.hgetall(customer_id)
end
```

How can I create a promise within a reusable function and make the main thread wait until the function returns the response from the promise?

EDIT:

It's been suggested the promise can be returned with a `then` chained in the main thread. However this still means any code in the main thread after after the function call executes before the `then` block.

EDIT 2:

After lengthy discussion with some IRL JS developer friends, it looks like trying to create a synchronous script is against the ethos of modern JS. I'm going to go back to my application design and work on making it async.

Comment: And the same problem again with not returning a promise. [Promise returns with 'undefined' or babel compiled code doesn't wait for return (async/await)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495714/promise-returns-with-undefined-or-babel-compiled-code-doesnt-wait-for-return#56495837)

Comment: Your main thread is NEVER going to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete.  An individual function can wait with `await`, but that function still immediately returns a promise and the main thread continues.  Javascript's main thread does not ever wait for asynchronous operations.  See the other answers for how to use promises properly, but don't be thinking any of that will "pause" the entire main thread.  It won't.

Comment: You cannot make the main thread wait. You need to `return` a promise from `get_values` and then use promise chaining (or `await`) in the `main_thread` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with `async`/`await`. I've replaced the redis with a timeout and an array for the data.

```js
async function main_thread() {
  console.log("Starting");
  values = await get_values(1);
  console.log(`After await: ${values}`);
  console.log("I expect to be after the values");
}

async function get_values(customer_id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const result = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log(`Resolving: ${result}`);
        resolve(result);
      }, 300);
  });
}

main_thread();
```

Further reading:

- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [Promise Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr. This is definitely the way to do what I wanted to do! However after some discussion with some JS devs I know IRL, it seems this behaviour is counter-intuitive to modern JS programming. I think I'm going to make some design changes within my application and built it to be more async. This is definitely the answer to the question asked!

Answer (score 2):

Simple as returning the promise (chain) from your function

```
function get_values(customer_id) {
  // Uses a callback for result
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    redis_client.hgetall(customer_id, function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log("About to resolve");
      resolve(result);
    });
  })
  .then(({result}) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}
```

And then in your main `async function` or `function`

`let result = await get_values();` or `get_values.then(function(result){})`

```
function main_thread() {
  console.log("Starting");
  values = get_values(1).then(function(values){
    console.log(values);
    console.log("I expect to be after the values");
  });
}

async function main_thread() {
  console.log("Starting");
  let values = await get_values(1);
  console.log(values);
  console.log("I expect to be after the values");
}
```

Comment: note: `thread` is a probably a misnomer here --- unless the thread is called from a web worker or otherwise on a separate node process for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Cody! But this doesn't appear to get the data back into the main thread? It's then encapsulated within the then function, and the data is still used after the main thread continues, correct?

Comment: That was kind of psuedo code at the end, I have updated it to make it more clear.

Comment: You must put the rest of your code inside the `get_values.then()` --- yes this gets ugly and nested quick, so use `async function main_thread(){}` and use `await foo()` to  avoid that kind of nesting.

Answer (score 2):

Return the promise in `get_values`

```
function get_values(customer_id) {
  // Uses a callback for result
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    redis_client.hgetall(customer_id, function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
      console.log("About to resolve");
      resolve(result);
    });
  })
  .then(({result}) => {
   reject(result);
  });
}
```

Now in your main thread, you could wait for it like:

```
function main_thread() {
  console.log("Starting");
  get_values(1).then(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prerak. Except If I have code after the get_values() function, that code will be run before the then, correct? I wish to pause this main thread to do this.

Comment: In that case, you can add that code inside the `then` block.